# Incorrect integer value when importing csv into a table via mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mysql-workbench

ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'subcategory_id' at row 1
SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`shelf` (`shelf_id`, `model_code_name`, `customer_friendly_name`, `sku_code`, `description`, `unitmeasure_id`, `category_id`, `subcategory_id`, `colour`, `size`, `vendor_id`) 
VALUES ('919025', '', 'MS919025', 'NULL', '1', '3', '31', '', 'W1800*D900*H724MM', '10', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`''` is not integer (between 31 and W1800)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the value of `subcategory_id` as integer value rather than `''`

So the query should be like

```
INSERT INTO db.shelf (shelf_id, model_code_name, customer_friendly_name, sku_code, description, unitmeasure_id, category_id, subcategory_id, colour, size, vendor_id) 
VALUES ('919025', '', 'MS919025', 'NULL', '1', '3', '31', someintegervalue, 'W1800*D900*H724MM', '10', '')
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```